# How can a variable declared through a provider be stored like a shared preference variable?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**I'm sorry if my question was ambiguous.**
I'll slowly explain what I want.
**I declared the variables to be used in the app using the provider**. This is the code I wrote.

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class CountPage extends ChangeNotifier {
  


  int _page = 150;
  int get page => _page;

  bool _visible = false;
  bool get visible => _visible;

  double _font = 40;
  double get font => _font;

  TextAlign align = TextAlign.center;

  Color selection =  Colors.red[200]!;

  change_align_left(){
    align = TextAlign.left;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_align_center(){
    align = TextAlign.center;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_align_right(){
    align = TextAlign.right;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_color_1() {
    selection =  Colors.green[200]!;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  change_color_2() {
    selection =  Colors.blue[200]!;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  change_color_3() {
    selection =  Colors.deepOrange[200]!;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  change_color_4() {
    selection =  Colors.pink[200]!;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  change_color_5() {
    selection =  Colors.red[200]!;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  change_color_6() {
    selection =  Colors.brown[200]!;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  change_color_7() {
    selection =  Colors.deepPurple[200]!;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_font_1() async {
    _font = 30;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_font_2() async {
    _font = 35;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_font_3() async {
    _font = 40;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  copy_on() {
    _visible = !_visible;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  page_down() {
    if (_page == 0) {
      _page = 0;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      _page--;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  page_up() {
    if (_page == 152) {
      _page = 152;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      _page++;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

**And then I created a button for the user to choose background color, text size, and text alignment, which is part of the code I created.**

```
class _Option_pageState extends State<Option_page> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    void initState() {
      super.initState();

    }
    
    final countPage = Provider.of<CountPage>(context);
    CountPage _countPage = Provider.of<CountPage>(context, listen: true);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: countPage.selection,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("설정"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(children: [
            Text(
              "글자 크기 ",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: countPage.font,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(child: Text('글자크기')),
                  Container(
                    width: 300,
                    color: Colors.green[200],
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              _countPage.change_font_1();
                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.looks_one_outlined)),
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              _countPage.change_font_2();
                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.looks_two_outlined)),
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              _countPage.change_font_3();
                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.looks_3_outlined)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color:  _countPage.selection,
              height: 50,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  TextButton(onPressed:()
                  {
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Color_choic()));
                  },
                    child: Text("색깔변경                                                  "),
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              height: 50,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text('글자정렬'),
                  Container(
                    width: 300,
                    color: Colors.lightGreen,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {countPage.change_align_left();},
                              icon: Icon(Icons.format_align_left)),
                          IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {countPage.change_align_center();},
                              icon: Icon(Icons.format_align_center)),
                          IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {countPage.change_align_right();},
                              icon: Icon(Icons.format_align_right)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );;
  }
}
```

This code changes the font size, background color, and text alignment while the app is running, but when you run the app again, **it returns to the first value.**

I want to change the size, color, and alignment values when I press the button, and **I want the changed values to remain changed even when I run the app again.**

I looked up a function called Shared Preference, but I don't know how to apply it to my code.

I'd appreciate it if you could suggest a way to solve my problem.

Don't hesitate to comment on my questioning method or code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, shared preferences can be a right approach: add the `shared_preferences` library to `pubspec.yaml`.

SharedPreferences needs an instance across and a string key to store the value in device storage:

Adding `static late SharedPreferences _prefs;` to your ChangeNotifier

Adding the instance to the initializer:

```
static Future init() async {
    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
```

So then your getters and setters would be something like this:

```
double _font = 40; //variable
  
double get font {
  return _prefs.getDouble("prefsFont") ?? _font; //return value of variable when there's nothing on preferences
}

set font(double font) {
  _font = font;
  _prefs.setDouble("prefsFont", _font); //saving variable to preferences when setting a value
}
```

If you want to "reset" values you just need to remove it from preferences:

```
void resetFont {
   _prefs.remove("prefsFont");
}
```

And if you want to remove all preferences:

```
static void clearAll() async {
   _prefs.clear();
}
```

Full class should look something like this:  ( I haven't tested it)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class CountPage extends ChangeNotifier {
  static late SharedPreferences _prefs;
  static const String prefsFont = "prefs_font";
  static const String prefsPage = "prefs_page";
  static const String prefsVisible = "prefs_visible";
  static const String prefsColor = "prefs_color";
  static const String prefsAlign = "prefs_align";

  int _page = 150;
  int get page {
    return _prefs.getInt(prefsPage) ?? _page;
  }

  set page(int page) {
    _page = page;
    _prefs.setInt(prefsPage, _page);
  }

  bool _visible = false;
  bool get visible {
    return _prefs.getBool(prefsFont) ?? _visible;
  }

  set visible(bool visible) {
    _visible = visible;
    _prefs.setBool(prefsFont, _visible);
  }

  double _font = 40;
  double get font {
    return _prefs.getDouble(prefsFont) ?? _font;
  }

  set font(double font) {
    _font = font;
    _prefs.setDouble(prefsFont, _font);
  }

  TextAlign _align = TextAlign.center;
  TextAlign get align {
    final alignValue = _prefs.getInt(prefsAlign) ?? _align.index;
    switch (alignValue) {
      case 0:
        return TextAlign.left;
      case 1:
        return TextAlign.center;
      case 2:
        return TextAlign.right;
      default:
        return TextAlign.center;
    }
  }

  set align(TextAlign align) {
    _align = align;
    _prefs.setInt(prefsAlign, _align.index);
  }

  Color _selection = Colors.red[200]!;
  Color get selection {
    Color color = Color(_prefs.getInt(prefsColor) ?? _selection.value);
    return color;
  }

  set selection(Color selection) {
    _selection = selection;
    _prefs.setInt(prefsColor, _selection.value);
  }

  static Future init() async {
    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  change_align_left() {
    align = TextAlign.left;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_align_center() {
    align = TextAlign.center;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_align_right() {
    align = TextAlign.right;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_color_1() {
    selection = Colors.green[200]!;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_color_2() {
    selection = Colors.blue[200]!;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_color_3() {
    selection = Colors.deepOrange[200]!;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_color_4() {
    selection = Colors.pink[200]!;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_color_5() {
    selection = Colors.red[200]!;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_color_6() {
    selection = Colors.brown[200]!;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_color_7() {
    selection = Colors.deepPurple[200]!;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_font_1() async {
    _font = 30;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_font_2() async {
    _font = 35;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  change_font_3() async {
    _font = 40;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  copy_on() {
    _visible = !_visible;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  page_down() {
    if (_page == 0) {
      _page = 0;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      _page--;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  page_up() {
    if (_page == 152) {
      _page = 152;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      _page++;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```